# Random Number Generator from input

Tags: cocoa-touch, random, numbers

I'm new to Xcode development, and i would like to know how can i generate random numbers from 2 inputs.

In IB i have 2 textfields (with Number pad) that indicate the interval of the numbers to generate (i.e. from 3 to 7). I would like to know how i get the inputs from the 2 textfields and do a method that generate random numbers from these inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **many** issues involved in trying to generate a truly random number. Note, for instance, that functions like *rand()* and *random()* generate sequences of numbers based on a 'seed value'. That means that if the seed value is the same, the sequence of numbers generated will be the same. There are various ways to use 'random' seeds - ie., using the current date and time - but the reliability and security of these methods is questionable.

As the number generators evolve, these issues get addressed, and therefore the later generators are usually better than the earlier ones: *rand* is generally not as random as *random*, and *random* is not as random as *arc4random*.

The current problem with *arc4random()*, which is documented in their manual pages, is that using a modulus calculation - as in "arc4random() % UPPER_LIMIT" - can introduce statistical bias, if UPPER_LIMIT is not an even number. Because of this, a new function was added to the arc4random family, called **arc4random_uniform**. It produces evenly distributed random numbers, regardless of the upper limit - and it is quite simple to use.

Using your example above, I would recommend you try generating your random number like this:

```
int value = low_bound + arc4random_uniform(width + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int low_bound = 3;
int high_bound = 7;
int width = high_bound - low_bound; // 4
int value = low_bound + arc4random() % (width + 1); // 3 + 0..4
```

Plus read the bounds from the fields, something like `bound = [[field text] intValue]`.

---

If you have trouble connecting the input fields to the code, you should read some Cocoa tutorial. There are several ways to do it, one of the most straightforward is declaring properties for the text fields in the controller class:

```
@interface Controller : UIViewController {}
@property(retain) IBOutlet UITextField *lowerBoundField;
@property(retain) IBOutlet UITextField *upperBoundField;
@end
```

Then you can connect the text fields in the Interface Builder to these outlets and work with them in code like this:

```
- (void) generateNumber {
    int lowerBound = [[lowerBoundField text] intValue];
    …
}
```

This is assuming we are talking about Cocoa Touch. In desktop Cocoa the situation is similar, just the details would be different.

Comment: I'm stuck at the input part. I can't get low_bound taking the textFieldA content. How to do that? If i use the code you insert to read the bounds, it says "expected identifier"

Comment: Thank you very much,i'll test it. I tried to read some tutorials 'bout textfields, but maybe i was searching for the wrong topic. Thanks for your help and your time!

Comment: You're welcome. Come back if you give it a try and still can't figure it out.